# In MySQL tables is it important to assign a default value to a column and why?

Tags: php, mysql, validation, default

When I update rows in a MySQL table I get a warning that "Field xyz doesn't have a default value". Which is true; it doesn't. I validate all data obtained from MySQL in my PHP code.

The fact that MySQL warns me makes me wonder: is it important to have default values assigned to all columns and if so, why? Performance? Predictable behavior? Simplification of the calling code? Other Best Practices or issues that I'm not aware of?

Comment: If a column doesn't have a default and you don't give it a value what should it's value be?

Comment: Not if there aren't sensible defaults; e.g. what should the default birth date be?

Comment: @duffymo `NULL`. Otherwise, you have to explicitly declare this column value with every insert, no?

Comment: @Ohgodwhy agreed; null is the only thing that makes sense.  That's what MySQL will assume if you say nothing.

Comment: You might be surprised then, that the implicit default value for `DATE` is `0`, unless the column allows `NULL`.

Comment: @MarcusAdams http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/date-and-time-types.html -- it's clear from the look of it that those dates/times are intended to represent nullish values, they're not even on the first day of the month, so most languages won't even attempt to parse them. The scary part is that the first timestamp column on a table defaults to NOW(), while the rest default to 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently, you are declaring your columns to be `NOT NULL`.  This is allowed and reasonable.  However, when you insert a new row into a table, MySQL needs to know what the value is.  Here are three ways you can put in a value:

- In the `insert` statement, you can explicitly list a value.
- In the `create table` statement, you can have a default value.  `NULL` is the default if none is listed.
- The table can have an `insert` trigger that specifies values for columns.

Because MySQL will use `NULL` as the default, you would be getting the error only when `NULL` is not allowed in the column.

EDIT:

The original answer is not 100% complete, because MySQL will make up values when used in its normal mode.  These are described [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/data-type-defaults.html) in the documentation.  So, the correct fourth bullet is:

- MySQL will insert default values of `0` for numerics and `''` for strings under most, but not all, circumstances

Because the circumstances are pretty broad, it is likely that you are actually operating in strict mode or have this default behavior turned off.

Comment: Different data types have different [implicit default](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/data-type-defaults.html) values for `NOT NULL` columns. `NULL` is only the implicit default value for columns that allow `NULL`.